# How to turn these two functions into one?

Tags: c#

first:

```
public static String ConvertServerToClientAdapter(String adapterServer)
    {
        string temp = adapterServer.Substring(0, adapterServer.IndexOf("/"));
        switch (temp)
        {
            case "f":
                {
                    return "FA";
                }
            case "g":
                {
                    return "Gi";
                }
            case "s":
                {
                    return "SE";
                }
            case "a":
                {
                    return "ATM";
                }
            default:
                return null;
        }
    }
```

second:

```
public static String ConvertClientToServerAdapter(String adapterClient)
{
    switch (adapterClient)
    {
        case "FA":
            {
                return "f";
            }
        case "Gi":
            {
                return "g";
            }
        case "SE":
            {
                return "s";
            }
        case "ATM":
            {
                return "a";
            }
        default:
            return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why would you want to combine those methods.  They do two seperate things.  Combining them would violate all sorts of best coding standards.

Comment: @Ramhound: I think it the thing he minds is that the string mapping is defined in two methods, which is not very DRY. The OP could have been more clear on this, though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can store the string pairs in a dictionary. That will reduce the duplication of having two places in the code saying that 'a' is paired with 'ATM'.

For the forward conversion, just index the dictionary. `return _dict[adapterServer];`.

Edit: maybe it should be TryGetValue if you want to return null for invalid input, rather than throwing exceptions.

For backward, use linq:

```
 return _dict.Elements.FirstOrDefault(e => e.Value == adapterClient).Key);
```

You can swap what is forward/backward depending on what is used more often, forward dictionary indexing is faster than linq.

Comment: +1 was going to post something similar - it must be noted though that this is only an option if there is an unambiguous one to one mapping from input values to result values and vice versa - also I'd keep the methods separate still

Comment: +1 Thought of the same myself. Just a sidenote, depending on the usage pattern (maybe the example is simplified, and there are hundreds of values in reality?), you might consider storing them in two dictionaries, to optimize lookup speed (base on key both ways). But if it's just the four values in the example above, just store them in a Dictionary, as suggested (alternatively a Tuple<string, string>).

Answer (score 1):

```
public static String Convert(String input)
{
    if (input.Contains("/"))
        switch (input.Substring(0, adapterServer.IndexOf("/")))
        {
            case "f":
                    return "FA";
            case "g":
                    return "Gi";
            case "s":
                    return "SE";
            case "a":
                return "ATM";
            default:
                return null;
        }
    }
    else 
        switch (adapterClient)
        {
            case "FA":
                    return "f";
            case "Gi":
                    return "g";
            case "SE":
                    return "s";
            case "ATM":
                    return "a";
            default:
                return null;
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you have is a map datastructure, but unfortunately .net does not provide one. If you are really worried about doing this sort of thing regulary, you could google for a ready-made map. You can also implement your own: Start with a generic Dictionary and override all the methods to ensure the the "value" side is unique, and add a second indexer property for the "reverse" lookup jdv-Jan de Vaan's solution is close to this!

Answer (score -1):

```
    public static String ConvertServerToClientAdapter(String adapterServer)
{

    switch (adapterServer.Substring(0, adapterServer.IndexOf("/")))
    {
        case "f":
            {
                return "FA";
            }
        case "g":
            {
                return "Gi";
            }
        case "s":
            {
                return "SE";
            }
        case "a":
            {
                return "ATM";
            }
        default:
           {
             switch (adapterClient)
{
    case "FA":
        {
            return "f";
        }
    case "Gi":
        {
            return "g";
        }
    case "SE":
        {
            return "s";
        }
    case "ATM":
        {
            return "a";
        }
    default:
        return null;
}
 }
      }
     }
```